# How to refer SVG/Images from Lightning Design System static resource to Lightning app?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, slds

Please guide me in using SVG/Icons given in Lightning Design system in Lightning component. Is it through ltng:require?

**EDIT:**

I need to refer SVGs in the LDS Bundle(static resource).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="400" height="400">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" stroke="black"
    stroke-width="5" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Here is an sample code for you.

[Reference 1](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder.htm)

[Reference 2](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/project/slds-lightning-components-workshop/slds-lc-4)

Comment: where should I add this DOCTYPE declaration? How to refer SVGs provided in LDS?

Comment: I already added reference 2. Please check.